# How to install custom AlertViews to my xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I found this great alert view style on GitHub :
https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView . How to install this to my xcode project ?

Comment: https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView#installation

Comment: did you install POD in your project ?

Comment: No i don't know about pod installation, any help ?

Comment: the tutorial given the proper guildlines , then why you take struggle

Comment: for pod purpose see this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and follow these steps :

1. **sudo gem install cocoapods**
2. Then change the path to the project you want to install POD

   **cd your_project_path**
3. Once the path is set do this in terminal :

   **pod init**
4. Serach for the pods (this may take some time):

   **pod search library_name**
5. [open pod file ]
   copy pod line and paste it in pod file
   usually pod lines look like this:

   **pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C'** [copy this much only ]

[image: Pod file]

6. the on terminal again

   **pod install**

and close current project and open .workspace file from now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

SCLAlertView-Objective-C is available through CocoaPods.

To install add the following lines in terminal.
Follow these steps:

1) cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/your project

2)  pod init

3)  open -a Xcode Podfile

4) pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C (Add this line between target and end).

5)   pod install

Hope this helps :)